# Vue.js: Passing Object with Symbol type value with v-bind

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm trying to pass an object using v-bind to my component:

```
<MyComponent v-bind="myObject" />
```

My object is using Symbols for some of the values:

```
{
  name: 'myCar',
  type: Symbol('sedan'),
}
```

Vue throws an error when trying to render this component:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot convert a Symbol value to a string
```

If I replace the value for myObject.type with a string, there is no longer an error.

I'm also able to pass the object fields separately without any issue:

```
<MyComponent :name="myObject.name" :type="myObject.type" />
```

Does Vue.js not support Symbol object values as props?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should only happen if you specifically declared `type`'s prop type as `String`.  Then it would expect a string but would get a symbol instead. Change `type`'s type in `MyComponent` to `Symbol` and it should work:

```
props: {
    type: {
        type: Symbol
    },
    name: {
        type: String
    }
}
```

Or there is somewhere else where you are trying to implicitly convert the Symbol to a String where it is not supported (without seeing your component code, we could only guess where that might be.)

Comment: Explicitly declaring the type like described has fixed the issue - I was using the same object for two different components & wasn't using the `type` variable in the second component, so it wasn't declared in `props`.

Comment: From this additional comment, it is clear the answer is not correct. The code fixes the problem but a reasoning is wrong. If there is prop validation mismatch, error message would be different. In this case the error happens because Vue is trying to [bind non-prop attribute](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html#Non-Prop-Attributes) and for that it needs to explicitly convert it's value to a string...

Comment: @MichalLevý - Your critique is clearly incorrect due to a faulty premise about prop validation.  See the proof:  https://jsfiddle.net/sh0ber/m9uwf72q  Note the mismatch and the error message.

Comment: @Dan Ok, I was wrong about the error message (as prop validation messages are usually different). But that doe not make me wrong - he explicitly said that he *wasn't using the type variable in the second component*. [This](https://jsfiddle.net/nxfec26u/) gives you same error. So the statement *This should only happen if you specifically declared type's prop type as String* is clearly incorrect as it is ignoring possibility of prop declaration completely missing (as was in this case)

Comment: @MichalLevý - I would advise you to look up the word *should* ("used to indicate what is probable.")  I stated that there may be a different implicit conversion taking place.  It would be good for you to learn to differentiate between stating one possibility and an absolute claim that this is the only way instead of giving unnecessary critique and introducing misinformation to the post.

Answer (score 0):

This error can happen in two cases:

1. The prop `type` is declared with incorrect [type](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html#Prop-Typeshttps://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html#Prop-Types) as suggested by Dan's answer
2. You are missing prop declaration completely (even in other components bound to same object) in which case Vue will try to [bind non-prop attribute](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html#Non-Prop-Attributes) to a root element of your component. And because HTML attributes can have only string value, it will try to convert it into a string. Fix for this case is either add prop declaration to your component even it is not in use there or disable this behavior by using `inheritAttrs: false` [component option](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html#Disabling-Attribute-Inheritance)

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/nxfec26u/)